# Getting EOF error after running GAM through Powershell

Tags: powershell, google-workspace

Running

```
gam ou_and_children Staff show filelist allfields todrive
```

to generate a listing of all files on our domain. Sometime after over 100,000 records I get an EOF error. Does anyone have any ideas on how to prevent this error?

Created a nocache.txt in my GAM folder. Errors still persist.